Spring Boot get shortened version of referenced entity
Suppose we have a Customer table with id, name, code, phone, email.
we also have a Employee table with id, CustomerId as a foreign key and name, phone, email.
we write Like
@Column
private Long customerId

Or
@ManytoOne
@JoinColumn
private Customer customer

If we use customerId for when we take it client side we may need name of him, but when we use Customer customer we get all the details which may be a security issue.
I want to only get a id, name and code so I used a
@Transient
Customer.CustomerShort

but I have to set it every time using repository.
I was wondering is there in spring boot something like
@JoinColumn
private Customer.CustomerShort customer

so that saving into database it should not get error (by using above I will get error since there is no CustomerShort table).
Is there any new approach that keeps in mind security, without using @Transient for CustomerShort so that we can get only some details ?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

By adding this to that employee pojo class it got worked
@joincolumn("customer_id)
private Customer customer

customer variable should be used
@JsonProperty("customer ")
public Map<String, Object> getCustomerDetails() {
     Map<String, Object> customerDetails = new HashMap<>();
     customerDetails.put("id", customer.getId());
     customerDetails.put("name", customer.getName());
     return customertDetails;
}


like customer object gets overided by below customer object
